# Socket: Client/Server does not work on different PC, but is Ok on same platform

Tags: sockets, networking

I wanted to send data from one linux app (finger reader) to an PC using sockets. The finger reader has very limited resources, and I choosen to use UDP packets to send data to a PC. I downloaded code for "Beginning Linux Programming" for both clients and servers, and it works fine, but only on the same platform. Using wireshark I can see that client data (finger reader) data is reached on the server PC, but the application just ignores it, the client retries and later timeout (TCP Only). I can ping from both sides, so I do have comms (wireshark confirms it). I also tried TCP and used netcat with similar results. The two 'devices' are connected via a switch. I also tried this on Ubuntu 13.04 and OpenSuse 12.3. I don't see any 'problem' with data data as displayed in wireshark (used ip.addr==xx or udp.port or tcp.port etc as filter)

Netcat (alias nc)

```
server: nc -u -l -v 1234   
client: nc -u 192.168.2.64 1234

server: nc -l -v 1234  
client: nc 192.168.2.64 1234 ,same PC Fine , different PCs .. no go.
```

Client software

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int sockfd;
    int len;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int result;
    char ch = 'A';

/*  Create a socket for the client.  */

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

/*  Name the socket, as agreed with the server.  */
    memset (&address,0, sizeof(address));
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.2.52");
    address.sin_port = htons(9734);
    len = sizeof(address);

/*  Now connect our socket to the server's socket.  */
    result = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, len);

    if(result == -1) {
        perror("oops: client3");
        exit(1);
    }
    /*  We can now read/write via sockfd.  */

    write(sockfd, &ch, 1);
    read(sockfd, &ch, 1);
    printf("char from server = %c\n", ch);
    close(sockfd);
    exit(0);
}
```

Server Code

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{ 
   int server_sockfd, client_sockfd;
   int server_len, client_len;
   struct sockaddr_in server_address;
   struct sockaddr_in client_address;

   //server_sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
   server_sockfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

   memset (&server_address,0, sizeof(server_address));
   server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
   server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
   server_address.sin_port = htons(9734);
   server_len = sizeof(server_address);
   bind(server_sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_address, server_len);

   /*  Create a connection queue, ignore child exit details and wait for clients.  */

   listen(server_sockfd, 5);

   signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);

   while(1) {
      char ch;

      printf("server waiting\n");

  /*  Accept connection.  */

      client_len = sizeof(client_address);
      client_sockfd = accept(server_sockfd, 
                             (struct sockaddr *)&client_address, 
                             &client_len);

  /*  Fork to create a process for this client and perform a test to see
      whether we're the parent or the child.  */

      if(fork() == 0) {

   /*  If we're the child, we can now read/write to the client on client_sockfd.
       The five second delay is just for this demonstration.  */

          read(client_sockfd, &ch, 1);
          printf (">> Rx %c ",ch);
          //sleep(5);
          ch++;
          write(client_sockfd, &ch, 1);
          printf (" Tx %c ",ch);
          close(client_sockfd);
          exit(0);
       }

   /*  Otherwise, we must be the parent and our work for this client is finished.  */

      else {
          close(client_sockfd);
      }
   }
 }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you do a telnet from the machine that is trying to do connect to the server machine. Please specify the port number as the port number on which the server is bound. Somethign like "telnet ip_address port_number". If you get a connection refused error, then that means your packets are getting dropped..  In that case, I woudl try "service iptables stop".

Comment: Is there a firewall running on the server PC?  If so, try disabling the firewall and see if it works after that.